# How to stop UITableView from attaching to the top

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I'm new to iPhone and having a hard time getting this one done. I know it's possible but can't find a way.
I have `UIView` that has a `UIToolbar` and a `UITableView` in it. I'm using IB and can see the toolbar at the top of the page and TableView below it but when I rum my application it only shows the `TableView`, the `Toolbar` for some reason is not shown (TableView covers it!).

Any help is appreciated, I hopt to to find a setting in IB but if I need to code for it that would be fine too. I've already tried setting the tableview's frame size (`self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 100, 320, 100);`) but this did nothing!

Thanks

Comment: What kind of view controller are you using

Comment: I had a UITableViewController but as your instruction I changed it to UIViewController.

Answer (score 0):

IB just shows the area of Toolbar not the actual toolbar its for designing purpose. You have to do it manually.

Comment: I've added a real toolbar and not just set the view's property to reseve the space. As I explained I have a UIView that holds a UITableView and a UIToolbar.

Answer (score 0):

First off if your not using a ViewController class please do so.

In IB place your table and toolbar inside a view, then set the view to the fileOwner(tableToolViewController)

Your header file of the view controller class should look something like this

```
  @interface tableToolViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {


    IBOutlet UITableView    *theTableView;
    IBOutlet UIToolbar      *yourToolbar
```

Now connect your outlets to your table and tool bar and that should do the trick

For calls that use self.tableView just use theTableView outlet instead

Comment: Matt,I've done all this but still the same result.I had it the same way only mine was extending UITableView but I changed it to follow your direction and still it's the same! not sure if this is important or not but I've used a tabbar application wizard and this is all in one of the tabs, the tabbar is shown just fine and when I added the toolbar I can see it fine in IB but as soon as I run it it seems for some reason it expands the table to cover all but the tabbar! Even if I reserve space for a navigation bar it won't do a thing! I'm sure this is something simple but it's driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Well I managed to resolve the issue. Just explaining it here so other who may have the same problem can benefit.

I started with what Matt suggested but it didn't help. Then I created a new project and started playing with different combinations of `UIView` and `UITableView` controllers and layouts.

It seems if the view controller is defined of type `UITableViewController` instead of defining it as `UITableVC` and the file owner is hooked to a tableview then the TV is expanded to cover the whole window and there is nothing you can do (I couldn't find a way!).

Even if you change the class definition and make it to extend `UIViewController` still this won't resolve the issue (strange!) but if simply create a new class extend `UIViewController` and copy paste all your code from old class and make sure file owner if hooked to the UIView then all works fine.

I'm sure there is an explanation for all this but for now I'm happy I can build what I want.

Thanks for the replies and help and happy coding.